# @angular/core/index has no exported member 'Renderer2'

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

`@angular/core` version 4.1.3 (`@angular/common`, `@angular/forms`, etc also have versions 4.1.3)

`@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` version 1.0.0-alpha.26

`typescript` version 2.3.3

Getting `Module @angular/core/index has no exported member 'Renderer2'` error in the following files after building:

```
/node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/buttons/radio.d.ts

/node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/datepicker/datepicker-input.d.ts

/node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/modal/modal-window.d.ts:

/node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/popover/popover.d.ts
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is because when you run npm install, the same libraries as the project you are running are not installed. In order to solve it:

1. Run the npm list command on the console located in the project folder.
2. Locate the bootstrap version you have installed.
3. Modify the package.json file with the specific version. (Remove ^).
4. Run "npm install" again.
5. Run the "ng serve" command.

Example:
I had to change:

"@ Ng-bootstrap / ng-bootstrap": "^ 1.0.0-alpha.21".

By

"@ Ng-bootstrap / ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-alpha.22".

In package.json file.